# Will Ubuntu work on the Asus - 2-in-1 15.6" Touch-Screen Laptop Q552UB-BHI7T12

Tags: wireless, drivers, uefi, hardware, asus

I'm looking into buy the [Asus - 2-in-1 15.6" Touch-Screen Laptop - Intel Core i7](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/asus-2-in-1-15-6-touch-screen-laptop-intel-core-i7-12gb-memory-1tb-hard-drive-aluminum-black/4415300.p). I'd like to know if Ubuntu would work on this computer, and if there are any complication. 
Primarily I'd like to know specifically about the Wireless hardware, and the EFI or BIOS interaction with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This model works well in both Ubuntu and Linux Mint however the brightness control keys on the keyboard for the screen don't work, but can be adjusted from the panel controls.

Everything else on this model works out of the box for both systems. An additional note the computer can be booted with secure boot on and the device boot menu is accessible by pressing escape at boot time.

Answer (score 1):

brightness control shortcut keys work fine with `acpi_osi=` added to end of boot args (`/etc/default/grub`) also the external subwoofer works fine with firmware mods using `hda-jackretask`. bumbelbee works great but requires very specific install directions ill try and post on ubuntu forums and add url later. The wireless sucks intel 7265 unless the power for both sata controllers is set to min_power

```
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy
```

which slows everything down or you can disable 802.11n `/etc/modprobe/iwlwifi.conf`

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable
```

If more specific directions would be helpfull to anyone ill try and do a proper write up.

Comment: This **should** be a proper write-up in the first place.